# Is $\text{Ind}_{Z(G)}^G \rho$ irreducible or not for nonabelian group $G$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a nonabelian group with center $Z(G)$. Let $\rho: Z(G) \to \text{GL}_n({\bf C})$ be an irreducible representation. Is $\text{Ind}_{Z(G)}^G \rho$ irreducible or not?

Comment: What is $Ind ^G _{Z(G)}\rho$?

Comment: Complex irreducible representations of abelian groups are one dimensional... So $n=1$.

Answer (score 6):

We claim that given the conditions set forth in the problem, $\text{Ind}_{Z(G)}^G \rho$ is always not irreducible.

Set $Z = Z(G)$. Let $W$ be an irreducible $Z$-representation. We would like to compute$$\langle\text{Ind}\,W, \text{Ind}\,W\rangle_G = \langle W, \text{Res}\,\text{Ind}\,W\rangle_H$$by Frobenius reciprocity. Since $Z$ is abelian, we know $W$ is of degree $1$. It follows that $\text{Ind}\,W$ is the span of $|G|/|Z|$ basis vectors, one for each coset of $Z$. For any $z \in Z$ and $s \in G$, observe that $zsZ = sz Z = sZ$. Thus, for $v_s \in \text{Ind}\,W$, where $v_s$ denotes the copy of $v$ corresponding to the coset $sZ$, we see that $z \cdot v_s = (z \cdot v)_s$. That is, each basis vector in $\text{Res}\,\text{Ind}\,W$ spans a copy of $W$. Thus,$$\text{Res}\,\text{Ind}\,W \cong (|G|/|Z|)W \implies \langle W, \text{Res}\,\text{Ind}\,W\rangle_H = \langle W, (|G|/|Z|)W\rangle_H = |G|/|H|.$$Since $G$ is nonabelian, this number is greater than $1$. We conclude $\text{Ind}\,W$ is not irreducible.

Comment: How do you know that $\mathrm{Ind} W$ has dimension $|G|/|Z|$. I can see that there is a spanning set of this cardinality, but I don't see why it is necessarily a basis. Is it obvious?

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, if you consider $W=\Bbb C.w$, then it seems more correct to argue as follows: $$z\cdot(g\otimes w)=(zg)\otimes w=(gz)\otimes w=g\otimes (zw)=\rho(z)\cdot(g\otimes w)$$ so that $g\otimes w$, provided it is nonzero, spans a $Z$-submodule isomorphic to $W$ (they have the same character). Does that seem fair?

Comment: It seems my first question is answered by the character formula for $\mathrm{Ind}\,W$, and this shows that the spanning set is indeed a basis, and the following comment shows that it splits, as a $Z$ module, into $[G:Z]$ copies of $W$. Ok, everything resolves itself : ) +1

Comment: Nice answer, giving the "full picture". You may be interested in visiting the chat room for finite group theory http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19567/finite-group-theory which we are trying to get going.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general this won't be irreducible: for example, if $G$ is a non-trivial finite group with $Z(G)$ trivial, then $\text{Ind}_{Z(G)}^G\text{triv}$ is the regular $G$-representation on ${\mathbb C}[G]$, which contains the proper non-trivial submodule ${\mathbb C}\cdot\sum_g g$.

Comment: In fact, it contains all irreducible $G$-modules as summands.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes :)